# How does apply work with functions that take in comma separated arguments?

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, push, apply

Okay, so I understand if you do:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

It would basically concatenate the first array in apply:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The supposed logic behind this is that [1, 2] is set as the **this** object on which push will be called with [3, 4].

If we say apply is:

```
fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])
```

Then **fun** is **push**, **thisArg** is **[1, 2]** and **[argsArray]** is **[3, 4]**

So to me, this is almost equivalent to:

```
[1, 2].push([3, 4])
```

But, push takes in **comma separated values** rather than an **array** or **array-like** object. How does apply make this work?

According to this: http://rusticode.com/2012/08/15/javascript-call-and-apply/, any other function that takes in comma separated values can instead be called with apply to do something similar to my above example, such as:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]); //max = 7
```

Unfortunately, there is no explanation.

How exactly does apply work with functions that take in comma separated arguments?

Answer (score 1):

`Function.prototype.apply` calls the specified function by passing each of the elements of its second argument (which must be an array or array-like) as individual arguments to the function.

So what you are doing in your first example is equivalent to

```
[1, 2].push(3, 4);
```

It is *not* equivalent to calling `[1, 2].push([3, 4]);` If it were, the result would be an array with another array nested inside it:

```
[1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

There *is* a method that does what you seem to think `apply` is doing. It's called `call`:

```
Array.prototype.push.call([1, 2], [3, 4]);
```

Comment: I understand that it's basically working like the first example you provided. I just didn't see any documentation stating that it will convert the arguments list into comma separated values to input into the push function. It's something that Javascript does internally? I wanted a more specific explanation to that.

Comment: You didn't find any documentation saying that because "comma separated values" is not the correct term. It's passing the elements of the array as separate arguments. That's what the first line of [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) says: _The `apply()` method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided as an array_. I don't know how it works internally, but that's the way it's designed to work.

Comment: If your question is about how `apply()` works _internally_, that would be an implementation-specific question and the answer would probably be different for every JavaScript implementation.

Comment: Okay, so I think understand it now. I was confused by that line in the MDN documentation until I see that "arguments" is actually the arguments **object**, correct? So, is it actually doing something like:

`[1, 2].push(arguments[0], arguments[1])` ?

Comment: No, arguments are simply the things you would ordinarily pass into a function between the parentheses. This is not the same thing as the arguments object.

Comment: Then, why in the MDN documentation, is the font of the word "arguments" different? That to me would imply it is the arguments object and not just regular arguments.

Comment: I don't know why they used a different font, but that line is not referring to the arguments object.

Answer (score 0):

`Function.prototype.apply(thisArg, [ argsArray])` takes `thisArg` as the first **required** argument and an optional second argument as array.

What it does that it returns the result of the calling function with the specified `thisArg` and the optional `argsArray` array.

But wait, the second argument is an array-like object but it's specifying the arguments of the calling function.

So for your example `Array.prototype.push.apply([1, 2], [3, 4])`, the calling function is `push` which takes a variable number of arguments and push into `this` array and `this` refer to the array `[1, 2]`. So the example works like

```
[1, 2].push(3, 4) // output: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But,

```
[1, 2].push([3, 4]) // output: [1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

For your second example, `Math.max.apply(null, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);` the `thisArg` is `null` because you are calling a prototype function of `Math`. Which doesn't allow an external `this` to perform any task. So the example works like:

```
Math.max(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) // output: 7
```

I hope it helps you.